# SwiftUI + Firestore - refresh previous view after updating data in modal sheet

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Say you have a view that displays a list of items. Clicking the item opens a modal sheet that allows the user to edit the item. On saving the sheet, the data is sent to the database to update and, on completion, the sheet is dismissed.

What's the best practice for updating the first view with the list of items? In my app, I'm currently using the "onDismiss" method to refresh the data from my cloud database (firestore).

However, there are cases when this doesn't work well. For example, if there's a cloud function that needs to run before the data is visible, then the data doesn't appear on the first refresh.

Is there a best practice for handling these types of updates?

Comment: if you are working with firestore, you could use .addSnapshotListener to update/refresh your variable/data automatically whenever there is a change in your database.

Comment: I stopped using the snapshot listeners because if the modal sheet view is open while a change to the record is pushed through (e.g. you're updating your profile and your rating changes), the listener will close the modal sheet and re-render the view.